# How to determine function name from inside a function

Tags: bash, function

If I have a Bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

f() {
  # echo function name, "f" in this case
}
```

Is there any way to do this? This could be used in help messages such as

```
printf "Usage: %s: blah blah blah \n" $(basename $0) >&2;
```

Only in this case what I wanted is not `$0`, which is the file name of the script.

Comment: Related: Bash logging framework that uses `FUNCNAME` array and other Bash variables: https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh.  See functions `log_debug_enter` and `log_debug_leave` in particular.

Comment: Anything for pure posix shell ?

Comment: @Itération122442: looks like in dash you can use `$_`, but I don't think this is standardized in POSIX.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

For Bash:
$FUNCNAME

Comment: `funcstack` in zsh.

Answer (score 109):

From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> FUNCNAME
>
> An array variable containing the names of all shell functions currently in the execution call stack. The element with index 0 is the name of any currently-executing shell function. The bottom-most element (the one with the highest index) is "main". This variable exists only when a shell function is executing. Assignments to FUNCNAME have no effect and return an error status. If FUNCNAME is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.
>
> This variable can be used with BASH_LINENO and BASH_SOURCE. Each element of FUNCNAME has corresponding elements in BASH_LINENO and BASH_SOURCE to describe the call stack. For instance, ${FUNCNAME[$i]} was called from the file ${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]} at line number ${BASH_LINENO[$i]}. The caller builtin displays the current call stack using this information.

When bash arrays are accessed without an index the first element of the array will be returned, so `$FUNCNAME` will work in simple cases to provide the name of the immediately current function, but it also contains all other functions in the call stack. For example:

```
# in a file "foobar"
function foo {
    echo foo
    echo "In function $FUNCNAME: FUNCNAME=${FUNCNAME[*]}" >&2
}

function foobar {
    echo "$(foo)bar"
    echo "In function $FUNCNAME: FUNCNAME=${FUNCNAME[*]}" >&2
}

foobar
```

Will output:

```
$ bash foobar
In function foo: FUNCNAME=foo foobar main
foobar
In function foobar: FUNCNAME=foobar main
```

Comment: I still don't get it. Why add the `[0]` if it's implied by accessing the undecorated variable?

Comment: Because it's deceptive and ignorant of the variable's actual type? Sure, it's not always necessary, but like many other bash-isms, it's a lazy convention. Better to be explicit than ambiguous.

Comment: This post will help understand the `$(foo)` part of this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17336953/264052

Comment: `$(foo)` is a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) where the command is the previously declared function `foo`. That function `foo` executes two commands: `echo foo` which print "foo" to stdout; and `echo "In function $FUNCNAME: FUNCNAME=${FUNCNAME[*]}" >&2` which uses [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) to print to stderr. Command substitution only uses stdout, not stderr.

Comment: If you are confused about the order of the output, lines writing to stderr can appear before lines writing to stdout even though they are later in the code. There are other answers that discuss buffering, but I needed to climb out of the rabbit hole before finding a rock-bottom definitive bash answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17378189/1279373 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/64755203/1279373

Answer (score 39):

I use `${FUNCNAME[0]}` to print current function name

Comment: @bschlueter but when you reference an array without treating it like an array in Bash, it just prints the first value; therefore, how is the accepted answer incorrect?

Comment: Sure, and that's convenient, but terrible for maintenance and testing. Don't be lazy, be explicit.

Answer (score 19):

The simplest way to get the function name (from inside a function) is dependent on which shell you are using:

###### Zsh version

```
someFunctionName() {
   echo $funcstack[1]
}
```

###### Bash version

```
someFunctionName() {
   echo ${FUNCNAME[0]}
}
```

###### Both

```
someFunctionName() {
  currentShell=$(ps -p $$ | awk "NR==2" | awk '{ print $4 }' | tr -d '-')
  if [[ $currentShell == 'bash' ]]; then
    echo ${FUNCNAME[0]}
  elif [[ $currentShell == 'zsh' ]]; then
    echo $funcstack[1]
  fi
}
```

###### A more robust version

```
columnX () {
    awk "{print \$$1}"
}
rowX () {
    awk "NR==$1"
}

checkShell() {
    ps -p $$ | columnX 4 | rowX 2 | tr -d - 
    # produces bash or zsh (or other shell name like fish)
}

showMethodName(){
    checkShell && echo ${FUNCNAME[0]} || echo $funcstack[1] 
}
showMethodName
```

Comment: Please stop abusing `###` in your answers.

Comment: I can confirm that this works with `zsh`. I was getting null results using `FUNCNAME`

Comment: Perhaps `###` should not exist on the platform then. Why provide something that is expected not to be used in any circumstance?

Comment: A four process pipe with questionable use of awk in a row to determine bash vs zsh? Oh my.  `test -n "$ZSH_VERSION" && echo $funcstack[1]; test -n "$BASH_VERSION" && echo ${FUNCNAME[0]}"`. Save the planet. Save four processes today :-)

Comment: Please stop referring to `###` as abuse. Abuse? Really? 
Do you need a hug?
Smile and have a great day ;D

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

```
# in a file "foobar"
foo() {
    echo "$FUNCNAME fuction begins"
}

foobar() {
    echo "$FUNCNAME fuction begins"
}

echo 'begin main'
foo
foobar
echo 'end main'
```

Will output:

```
begin main
foo fuction begins
foobar fuction begins
end main
```

Answer (score 0):

Without checking which shell is being used, this works with zsh, bash, and bash emulating sh. (However, this still breaks with sh and dash, and possibly others. Feel free to edit and improve.)

```bash
funcName() {
    if [ -n "${FUNCNAME[0]}" ]; then
        local function_name="${FUNCNAME[0]}";  # bash, bash emulating sh
    else
        local function_name="${funcstack[1]}";  # zsh
    fi

    echo "$function_name"  # Outputs: funcName
}
```