# In bash script, how to use function exit status in while loop condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Below is my shell script. How to compare the exit status of function in while loop condition block ? Whatever I return from `check1` function my code enters into while loop

```
#!/bin/sh
    check1()
    {
            return 1
    }

    while [ check1 ]
    do
            echo $?
            check1
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "Called"
            else
                    echo "DD"
            fi
            sleep 5
    done
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're calling check1 twice?  You should be able to assumed it was "Called" each time through that loop...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the `test` command - also known as `[`.  So:

```
while check1
do
    # Loop while check1 is successful (returns 0)

    if check1
    then
        echo 'check1 was successful'
    fi

done
```

Shells derived from the Bourne and POSIX shells execute a *command* after a conditional statement.  One way to look at it is that `while` and `if` test for success or failure, rather than true or false (although `true` is considered successful).

By the way, if you must test `$?` explicitly (which is not often required) then (in Bash) the `(( ))` construct is usually easier to read, as in:

```
if (( $? == 0 ))
then
    echo 'worked'
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

The value returned by a function (or command) execution is stored in $?, one solution would be:

```
check1
while [ $? -eq 1 ]
do
    # ...
    check1
done
```

A nicer and simpler solution may be:

```
while ! check1
do
    # ...
done
```

In this form zero is true and non-zero is false, for example:

```
# the command true always exits with value 0
# the next loop is infinite
while true
    do
    # ...
```

You can use `!` to negate the value:

```
# the body of the next if is never executed
if ! true
then
    # ...
```

Comment: You might also consider `until` rather than `while !`

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, another way is using the function exit code inline of the `while`

```
 while check1  ; [ $? -eq 0 ] ; do
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29162515/32453)

You can also use parameters if you change your method to the "echo" [style return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17336953/32453).

```
 while [ $(check1 my_param) < 33] ; do ...
```