# How can I directly put a return value of a bash function into an if-statement?

Tags: bash, function, shell

I have following function which checks connection for internet (I know there are better ways to check for internet connection but that's not the topic):

```
function checkInternet() {
    local HOST="http://google.com"
    local WGET="/usr/bin/wget"
    $WGET -q --tries=10 --timeout=10 --spider $HOST

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        echo "online"
    else
        echo "offline"
    fi
}
```

Now I want to request the return value of the function directly in an if-statement:

I tried several scripts similar to e.g. this one (what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336915/return-value-in-bash-script)):

```
if( $(checkInternet) -eq "online" )
then
    echo "Function returned online"
else
    echo "Function returned offline"
fi
```

I don't want to initialisize further variables before the if-statement what I meant with "directly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in BASH to check the output of a function:

```
[[ $(checkInternet) == online ]] && echo "Function returned online" || 
        echo "Function returned offline"
```

To compare conditions use `[[...]]` (preferable) or `[...]`.

You can simplify above to to just this without evaluating any conditions:

```
echo "Function returned $(checkInternet)"
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working. I had tried your first part of the code but used quotes: `[[ $(checkInternet) == "online" ]]`.

Comment: Yes quotes are recommended if string may contain whitespaces.

Answer (score 2):

A case statement will do this nicely and without non-portable bashisms:

```
case $(checkInternet) in
  (online)  echo is online;;
  (offline) echo is offline;;
esac
```

You can also make your checkInternet return a status, which simplifies things in an `if`:

```
...
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    true
else
    false
fi
```

Along with

```
if checkInternet; then
   # online
else
   # offLine
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, also a nice solution, but I've taken anubhava's solutions already

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 You shouldn't. It's clearly inferior, since it uses bashisms. You will never regret a portable POSIX shell solution. There will come a day when you find yourself on a non-Linux box. Be wise, learn proper shell programming from the beginning and don't be trapped by **all the world's a bash**.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355, don't forget to accept it then: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Jens, if you want to return based on wget's exit status, just leave it as the last line of the function (since $? -eq 0 is already "success")

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually  returning a value from your checkInternet () function.  If you look at the example you posted, you'll see that their function has a return statement at the end.

Comment: It's true, but the solutions also advise `echo` and not `return`