# Shell Script to Generate Fibonacci Series

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a recursive function to calculate the n-th number from Fibonnaci series. I already find a lot of solutions for this problem, but I what to know why mine doesn't work. Thanks.

```
function fib ()
{
        if [ $1 -eq 1 -o $1 -eq 2 ]
        then
                return 1
        else
               let nr=$1-1
               fib $nr
               rez1=$?
               let nr=$1-2
               fib $nr
               rez2=$?
               let rez=$rez1+$rez2
               return $rez
        fi
}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17336915/632407

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, all of your variables are global, which means that when you make a recursive call it overwrites the values of `nr`, `rez`, `rez1`, and `rez2`. You can fix this by declaring them as `local`:

```
fib() {
    local nr rez rez1 rez2
    if [ $1 -eq 1 -o $1 -eq 2 ]; then
        return 1
    else
        let nr=$1-1
        fib $nr
        rez1=$?
        let nr=$1-2
        fib $nr
        rez2=$?
        let rez=$rez1+$rez2
        return $rez
    fi
}
```

The second problem is that you're trying to pass a number via the return status of the function. The return status is a 1-byte unsigned integer, which means it can't get bigger than 255 (after which it wraps around to 0. It's really intended to give success/failure results (and maybe some information about what failed), with 0 indicating success and anything else indicating an error. Trying to use it for something else is asking for trouble. You can see the results here (from the `local`ized version of the function):

```
$ fib 11; echo $?
89
$ fib 12; echo $?
144
$ fib 13; echo $?
233
$ fib 14; echo $?
121
```

The 14th Fibonacci number is 377, but that's over 255 so it came out as 377-256 = 121. To fix this, return the result by `echo`ing it to stdout and capture it with `$( )`:

```
fib() { 
    local nr rez rez1 rez2
    if [ $1 -eq 1 -o $1 -eq 2 ]; then
        echo 1
    else
        let nr=$1-1
        rez1=$(fib $nr)
        let nr=$1-2
        rez2=$(fib $nr)
        let rez=$rez1+$rez2
        echo $rez
    fi
}
```

...this does have a disadvantage, though: it's much slower, because every call to `fib` has to run as a subprocess, and creating subprocesses is computationally expensive. (This actually would've solved the global-variable problem, since variables inherit down to subprocesses but not up from them; but it only solves it by accident.)

Take-home lesson: shell scripts aren't the right language for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

It is way easier in something like `awk`:

```
$ echo 11 | awk 'function fib(n) {
    return n<2 ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
} $1+0>0 {print fib($1)}'
89

$ echo 35 | awk 'function fib(n) {
    return n<2 ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
} $1+0>0 {print fib($1)}'
9227465
```

Or, if you want comma separated digits:

```
$ echo 39 | awk 'function fib(n) {
    return n<2 ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
} $1+0>0 {printf ("%'"'"'d\n", fib($1))}'
63,245,986
```