# Obtaining an integer (greater than 255) from the system function in C++

Tags: c++, bash, return, system

I have a relatively simple problem which I cannot seem to do. What I need to do is retrieve an integer from a bash script using the `system` function in a C++ program. My understanding is that `system` by default returns an integer, so I should be bale to do something like

```
int returnedVal = system ("myscript");
```

however the main problem is bash scripts do not have return values, just a flag between 0 and 255 for whether they were successful or not. I have tried doing something like writing to a text file in the script and then reading in a file, however this caused some issues and I would like to avoid that if possible. Does anyone know the easiest way to do this? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Shell scripts can return values with `exit` e.g. `exit 1`.

Comment: my understanding is that they can only return an integer between 0 and 255

Comment: Your understanding is correct. If you need to pass larger integers, modify your question (and title). One solution could be a pipe; many shell scripts write text (like, textual representation of numbers) to stdout which is then captured by calling scripts. For example `lines = $(wc -l $file)`.

Comment: Return the value using some other form of IPC than exit codes. For example; use pipes (stdout and stdin can easily be used that way for example). Ohh, and *don't* use `system` it is fraught with bad surprises and security issues (use one of the `exec*` functions instead).

Comment: What is `myscript` doing? In some cases you might not need any script

Answer (score 3):

POSIX exit(3) says:

> The value of status may be 0, EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE, [CX] [Option
>   Start]  or any other value, though only the least significant 8 bits
>   (that is, status & 0377) shall be available to a waiting parent
>   process.

This means that no value greater than what is possible to represent with 8 bits can exit from a normal process termination via call to `exit` then parent can't catch more.

More on this. Don't use returned value to transmit some data, it is primarily intended to represent a success or failure status. 0 value represent successful, any other a failure.

If you want your processes to communicate something, then you need some communication channel (file, pipe, etc).

Answer (score 1):

If `myscript` -like many scripts or programs- [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)-s something (e.g. some numbers or strings) on its *stdout*, you might use (on POSIX) [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) in your program.
When successful `popen` would give a `FILE*` stream for `<stdio.h>` routines (that you could read with  `fscanf` etc).

<sup>(I am guessing that you are using some Linux or POSIX system)</sup>

But [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) catches the [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) status (actually also other terminations, e.g. [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)-s, see [waitpid(2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html))) of `myscript`. It don't care about the output of `myscript` which gets inserted in the standard output of your program.

Don't forget to use [pclose(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pclose.3.html) (not `fclose`) to close that `popen`-ed stream. Read also [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

For example, this code reads the number from the output of the `wc -l /etc/fstab` command

```
FILE*p = popen("wc -l /etc/fstab", "r");
if (!p) { perror("popen"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
int n= 0;
if (fscanf(p,"%d", &n)<=0) { perror("fscanf"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE; };
if (pclose(p)>0) /*wc failed*/ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
printf("your fstab has %d lines\n", n);
```

You should read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (freely downloadable). You may want to use other things (e.g. some system calls like fork(2), execve(2), waitpid(2), pipe(2), dup2(2); see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)).

There are many other ways of doing some [Inter-Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), including [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s and [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)-s.

Beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) when running, with `popen` or `system`, some *computed* string containing a command.

Some libraries (notably [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) for C++) offer other ways of running programs and communicating with them.

Answer (score 0):

The [`system` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) says, after discussing all kinds of failures:

> If all system calls succeed, then the return value is the
>             termination status of the child shell used to execute command.
>             (The termination status of a shell is the termination status of
>             the last command it executes.)

For clarity one could add that the shell's exit value is either the numerical argument to the `exit` command, or — if none is encountered — the exit status of the last command which was executed, i.e. the value of `$?`. That exit value is passed by the operating system to the shell's parent (which may be another shell) via the [`waitpid()`  function.](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) That way the exit status of the "leaf" process is propagated until it reaches `system`, and finally your program.

I do not see why what you want to do should not be possible.

Comment: Add a link to this question and you have a +1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336915/return-value-in-bash-script

Comment: Just make sure that `myscript` is actually setting the appropriate exit code.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I understand.  Are you saying it is not possible?

Comment: Two negations give a positive: I do think it is possible, indeed. Why do you not post a complete test case? A minimal script, a minimal C program containing a `printf` of the `system` call, and a description of your environment. Then we can talk business beyond "I do not see" or "should".