# bash: function returning output instead of output status

Tags: bash

I have a small bash script as below

```sh
function getUptime() {

    uptime 2>/dev/null
    return "$?"
}

resultReceived=$(getUptime)
echo "Result: $resultReceived"
```

And when I execute the script, instead of `0` I am getting `uptime` command output. Where I am doing the mistake. Please help.

Debug Output

```
 tmp bash -x testingscript.sh
++ getUptime
++ uptime
++ return 0
+ resultReceived='11:47  up 3 days, 19:24, 7 users, load averages: 1.88 1.78 2.04'
+ echo 'Result: 11:47  up 3 days, 19:24, 7 users, load averages: 1.88 1.78 2.04'
Result: 11:47  up 3 days, 19:24, 7 users, load averages: 1.88 1.78 2.04
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336915/return-value-in-a-bash-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed the exit status and the output.
With `$(getUptime)` you get the output of your function, not the exit status.

You could change your function, but then the name will not match it's functionality.

```
function getUptime() {

    uptime >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    echo "$?"
}
```

I suppose it's better not to change the function, instead change the code at:

```
resultReceived=$(getUptime)
exitstatus=$?
echo "Result: $resultReceived, exitstatus: $exitstatus"
```