# How to return an array from read command in a function?

Tags: arrays, bash, return-value

I have a small problem in here with `bash`
I wrote an `array` in a simple `function` and I need to `return` it as an `array` with `read` command and also need to `call` it somehow.

```
function myData {
    echo 'Enter the serial number of your items : '
    read -a sn
    return ${sn[@]}
}
```

for example like this ???

> $ ./myapp.sh
>   
> Enter the serial number of your items : 92467 90218 94320 94382

```
myData    
echo ${?[@]}
```

Why we don't have return value in here like other languages ?
thanks for your help...

Comment: Have a look at [Return value in a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17336915/3266847) to understand the meaning of `return` in Bash – it's meant to convey exit status, not to return data from a function.

Comment: thnx a lot do you have any suggestion to return data please? (in my example)

Comment: You *don't*. You either set a global variable, or you write to standard output and capture that with a command substitution.

Comment: the simplest example is `myfunc() { echo got input as $@ ; } ; var=$(myfunc some text); echo "$var"` . Good luck.

Comment: Is `myData` going to use the input (92467 ...), or `read` from stdin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others mention, the builtin command `return` is intended to send the `exit status` to the caller.
If you want to pass the result of processing in the function to the
caller, there will be several ways:

1. **Use standard output**

   If you write something to the standard output within a function, the output
   is redirected to the caller. The standard output is just a non-structured
   stream of bytes. If you want to make it have a special meaning such as an
   `array`, you need to define the structure by assigning a delimiter to some
   character(s). If you are sure each element do not contain space, tab, or
   newline, you can rely on the default value of `IFS`:

   ```
   myfunc() {
       echo "92467 90218 94320 94382"
   }

   ary=( $(myfunc) )
   for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
       echo "$i"
   done
   ```

   If the elements of the array may contain whitespace or other special
   characters and you need to preserve them (such a case as you are handling
   filenames), you can use the null character as the delimiter:

   ```
   myfunc() {
       local -a a=("some" "elements" "contain whitespace" $'or \nnewline')
       printf "%s\0" "${a[@]}"
   }

   mapfile -d "" -t ary < <(myfunc)
   for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
       echo ">$i"           # The leading ">" just indicates the start of each element
   done
   ```
2. **Pass by reference**

   As other languages, `bash`>=4.3 has a mechanism to pass the variable by
   reference or by name:

   ```
   myfunc() {
       local -n p="$1"     # now p refers to the variable with the name of value of $1
       for (( i=0; i<${#p[@]}; i++ )); do
           ((p[i]++))      # increment each value
       done
   }

   ary=(0 1 2)
   myfunc "ary"
   echo "${ary[@]}"        # array elements are modified
   ```
3. **Use the array as a global variable**

   Will be needless to explain its usage and pros/cons.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, but as I mentioned in my title what about read command, may I ask you give me an example with read command ? I want to get array from read command in function.

Comment: Sorry for my insufficient explanation. In your case, just say `echo "${sn[@]}"` and split into an array within the caller. Or you don't even have to generate an array in the function and just `echo` the space-separated string then let the caller split it. Have I made myself clear?

Comment: thanx it was perfect, but I don't want to do this, I think this way is not very nice, let me sleep on it and search more, if I couldn't find another solution I'll use your method rep ++

Comment: All right. If you find a better way, I'd be happy to know about it. Good luck!