# Bash while with multiple conditions and a function call

Tags: bash

I can't figure out the bash syntax of a while statement with two conditions where one of them is a function call which returns a number.

I removed all [ ( in this example - but I think I tried them all :)

```
func() {
    return 12
}

ATTEMPTS=0
MAXATTEMPTS=2

while func -gt 0 && $ATTEMPTS -lt $MAXATTEMPTS 
do
  echo "Hello"
  ATTEMPTS=$((ATTEMPTS+1))
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change return to echo and use `$(func)` (and bring back the brackets so you don't get `-gt: command not found`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
func() {
  echo 12
}

ATTEMPTS=0
MAXATTEMPTS=2

while [[ $(func) -gt 0 ]] && [[ $ATTEMPTS -lt $MAXATTEMPTS ]]
do
  echo "Hello"
  ATTEMPTS=$((ATTEMPTS+1))
done
```

Comment: Thanks alot for quick reply - it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to debug, I would often run the condition by itself in the shell and inspect the results. This works because a condition is just a normal bash statement with an exit code. In this case:

```
$ func() { \
    return 12 \
}
$ func -gt 0 && $ATTEMPTS -lt $MAXATTEMPTS 
$ echo $?
12
```

This hopefully makes it obvious you're just calling the function with arguments that it ignores (you can show this by calling `echo "$@"` in the function).

To make it work like you probably want, you need to separate statements.

But it also seems like you got caught up in the way bash uses `return` which is not like most programming languages, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17336953/2447844 for explanation and a better solution. Basically, you want to use `echo` instead of `return` in the function.

But if you really can't change the func function, I suggest you instead do the following:

```
func
FUNC_VALUE=$?
while [ $FUNC_VALUE -gt 0 ] && [ $ATTEMPTS -lt $MAXATTEMPS ]
...
```