# Why does my stderr line get printed first, when it's after my stdout line?

Tags: c, stdout, stderr, stdio

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

        printf("Hello, World!");

        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "There's been an error.");

 }
```

When I run this in the console, I first see the `stderr` (line 7), then the `stdout` (line 5), even though that's the opposite order. The closest answer I could find is here: [Why is the STDOUT line printed after the STDERR line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378189/why-is-the-stdout-line-printed-after-the-stderr-line), but that appears to be for (a) perl, and (b) buffering `stdout` when writing to a file.

Comment: `stdout` is (line)buffered even when printed to console. Add `\n` and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Even error messages (or maybe especially error messages) should end with newlines.  If you want to see the output, end the message with a newline.  Even that isn't guaranteed — you'd need to use `fflush(stdout)` or `fflush(NULL)` to do that.

Comment: @GovindParmar: strictly, `stderr` is not fully buffered.  C11 [§7.21.3 Files](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3) says: _As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; …_  It could be line-buffered or unbuffered.

Comment: The program has no newlines output and no flushing. The output streams are flushed and closed when a program ends. I'm not sure what decides which one is closed first, but if they are both buffered, that is when their outputs will be seen.