# Get name of calling function in zsh

Tags: zsh

I want to get function caller name in shell script sometime, in bash it works with `${FUNCNAME[1]}`

`${FUNCNAME[1]}` is a  (caller name)

`${FUNCNAME[0]}` is c  (current name)

but it not work in zsh

ie i want to know which function call me in function c

```
function a(){
    c
}

function b(){
    c
}

function c(){
     #if a call me; then...
     #if b call me; then...
}
```

Comment: Duplicate, consider my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835943/how-to-determine-function-name-from-inside-a-function/62527825#62527825

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The function call stack is in the variable `$funcstack[]`.

```
$ f(){echo ${funcstack[1]};}
$ f
f
```

So in `c` the calling function (`a` or `b`) is `$funcstack[2]` or perhaps more conveniently `$funcstack[-1]`.

Comment: zsh array indexes start from 1. There's a compatibility option `KSH_ARRAYS` to start from 0.

Comment: My edit `${funcstack[1]}` turns out only to be needed with `emulate sh`. Sorry, I can't work out how to revert it.

Comment: @TomHale It seems you have to edit again, and click *rollback* on the version you want back. I just did it, hope it doesnt cause you any penalty points. Thanks.

Comment: I had to re-read the second part of your answer three times to understand it, as you mix function names from the question and from your answer. The answer would benefit from rewording it.

Answer (score 10):

#### Generic solution

- Works whether array indexing starts at 0 (option `KSH_ARRAYS`) or 1 (default)
- Works in both `zsh` and `bash`

---

```bash
# Print the name of the function calling me
function func_name () {
    if [[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "${FUNCNAME[1]}"
    else  # zsh
        # Use offset:length as array indexing may start at 1 or 0
        printf "%s\n" "${funcstack[@]:1:1}"
    fi
}
```

**Edge case**

The difference between `bash` and `zsh` is that when calling this function from a `source`d file, `bash` will say `source` while `zsh` will say the name of the file being sourced.