# Get the function name inside a Z shell function

Tags: function, zsh

The solution for Bash is here: [How to determine function name from inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1835943/241142)

How can I do the same thing in Z shell, getting the function name from inside the function?

Update: there is a similar but distinct question asking about getting the name of the *calling* function.  It is quite plain that the *calling* function and *current* function are distinct things. Although the answers are closely related, the questions are entirely distinct.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426565/get-name-of-calling-function-in-zsh) for a comparision of bash and zsh in this respect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get name of calling function in zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426565/get-name-of-calling-function-in-zsh)

Comment: That **question** is _a different question,_ but the answer does give an answer to this question.  That asked for the zsh version of `${FUNCNAME[1]}` and I asked for the zsh version of `${FUNCNAME[0]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31426948/241142 (even though the question it is attached to asked for the *calling* function and not the *current* function, it gave the *current* function).  I'll repeat it here:

The function call stack is in the variable `$funcstack[]`.

```
$ your_function(){echo $funcstack[1];}
$ your_function
your_function
```