# Bash script - function to save output to a file

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to save all output of a collection to separate files. For example one function will be like:

```
function kernel_info(){
   echo "Kernel version: $(uname -v)"
}
```

I want to write this output to file which will have kernel_info as it name.
Similarly I will create other functions to gather other information like hostname, etc.
How can I write a function which I can call every time I want to save the information to a file on disk?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tee`.

```
kernel_info () {
   { printf 'Kernel version: '
     uname -v
   } | tee -a /path/to/kernel_info
}
```

This function will write the combined output of `printf` and `uname` to the given file, and continue to write the same to standard output.

The `-a` option makes `tee` append to the file.

If you want to parameterize the function, you can.

```
kernel_info () {
   local fname
   fname=${1:-/default/path/to/kernel_info}
   { printf 'Kernel version: '
     uname -v
   } | tee -a "$fname"
}

kernel_info  # Writes to /default/path/to/kernel_info
kernel_info /var/log/kernel_info  # Write to an alternate file
```

Comment: The second one leaks `fname`, shouldn't that be `local`?

Comment: It can be. It's not often I'm too concerned about such leaks, so I don't immediately jump to using `local`.

Comment: (`local` also as the "distinction" of being the only non-POSIX part of the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the naming via perusing [How to determine function name from inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835943/how-to-determine-function-name-from-inside-a-function) - and simply

```
... | tee "${FUNCNAME}.log"
```

within the function where you'd like to log to a specifically-named output file.

Comment: the tee function works well.  I am trying to zip it at the same time but not able to.

|tee "$directory_name""_${FUNCNAME}.txt" > /dev/null
How can I use tee in conjunction with tar in the above line?

Answer (score 0):

Define a list of functions to loop over then call them and then redirect the result into a file,

`>` replace, `>>` append

```
#!/bin/bash

function local_hostname() {
    echo "Hostname: $(hostname)"
}

function kernel_info() {
    echo "Kernel version: $(uname -v)"
}

function write_to_file() {
    > file.txt

    funcs=(
        local_hostname
        kernel_info
    )
    for func in ${funcs[*]}
    do
       $func >> file.txt
    done
}

write_to_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it simple...

```
$: tst() { date ; } >>log
$: ls -l log
ls: cannot access 'log': No such file or directory
$: tst
$: cat log
Wed, Jun 17, 2020  8:12:10 AM
$: tst
$: cat log
Wed, Jun 17, 2020  8:12:10 AM
Wed, Jun 17, 2020  8:12:17 AM
```